# Fire a function when clicking on a button inside a mui component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a MUI static date picker looking as following:

[image]

How can i detect clicks on the arrows in order to fire a function? I have a calendar next to this component - and i want to show the corresponding month to the datepicker.

I'm new to this, so pardon me for asking for something that is not possible.

```
import { StaticDatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/StaticDatePicker';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `onMonthChange` property to listen for changes in a month. The callback returns Date string which you can convert to a date object:

```
<StaticDatePicker onMonthChange={(date) => {
   console.log(new Date(date).getMonth())
}}/>
```